# CSS: Flexible featured image is problematic in smaller sizes

Tags: css, wordpress, image, blogs

// Edit: solved, there was an additional "margin-bottom: 18px" in my code that came from a different part of the stylesheet. In smaller sizes this margin started to show up gradually until it was the full 18px. THANKS anyways guys! :))

I have a probem with a featured image on my blog. I want it to be 100% in width and max. 500px in height, cropped to the center when it's getting reduced in height. I'm using a DIV container with display: flex for that. However when I resize the browser window to smaller sizes the container gets higher than the actual image, showing a visible gap. How can I get rid of that? In my example images the gap has a turquoise (background) color.

[At 1920 px width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95TkR.jpg)

[At 814 px width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdoqz.jpg)

HTML:

```
<div class="featured-img clearfix">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" srcset="" sizes="(max-width: 2400px) 100vw, 2400px" width="2400" height="1350">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.featured-img {
    max-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I tested in Firefox browser, current version. Is there anything that I'm missing?

I tried adding min-height and height values, no success. I was expecting the container to adapt to the image, only cutting off parts when the image would be over 500x in height.

Comment: style the image in CSS not the container